# Old Fantasy Novel - set in different world - I read this in 1960's or early 70's kind of like moorcock but not him

Tags: story-identification, novel

Fantasy Novel - set in different world - the protagonist is a warrior from another land - he is rescued and helps a city defend itself from assault but this city is doomed. A second assault by demon / ant like creatures comes and they flee on a boat to an island sanctuary of a ruined civilization with a goddess (?) protector. He then goes off on a journey to find his origin in a far city, where he faces a group of 3 enemies: a general, a magician, and an creature of darkness that cannot abide light.  He is told he is their fourth and from another world, arriving through gates. The magician and general kill each other, and he destroys the evil creature

Comment: There is some resemblance to M. John Harrison's *Viriconium* books (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viriconium), but also enough differences that I don't believe it is the correct answer.

Comment: Thank You for the Thought. I have read Pastel City by Harrison and it is not the same at all. The book I remember was set in a medieval fantasy construct with magic and Gods . Pastel City is set in far future with Tech laying around from the old days .